# The task is to import excel file using procedures. I want to call the stored procedure(works for single row) with PHP code. How Can I do this?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, vue.js, stored-procedures

This is from the Query Builder

```
$result = DB::table('tablename')->insert($dataset);
```

This is what I am trying

```
$result = DB::update('exec SaveTestItem ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?', $dataset);
```

SaveTestItem is the name of the procedure that saves one row each to the database.
My Question is, Do I need a different stored procedure to save multiple rows or I execute from the PHP code with loop to call the stored procedure? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: If the procedure only accepts scalar values, and you want to pass "rows" you'll need to either loop through the rows, running the procedure over and over again (which would be quite slow), or you could change your procedure to accept an table type parameter.

Comment: I will go with the looping for now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use loop, which will be easier than table type params

Comment: this must be comment